# Shift/Reduce conflicts in a propositional logic parser in Happy

Tags: parsing, haskell, shift-reduce-conflict, happy

I'm making a simple propositional logic parser on happy based on [this BNF definition](http://www2.cs.siu.edu/~rahimi/cs537/slides/Formal%20Presentation%20of%20Prop%20and%20Pred%20Logic.pdf) of the propositional logic grammar, this is my code

```
{
module FNC where
import Data.Char 
import System.IO
}

-- Parser name, token types and error function name:
--
%name parse Prop
%tokentype { Token } 
%error { parseError }

-- Token list:
%token
     var { TokenVar $$ }  -- alphabetic identifier
     or { TokenOr }
     and { TokenAnd }
     '¬' { TokenNot }
     "=>" { TokenImp } -- Implication
     "<=>" { TokenDImp } --double implication
    '(' { TokenOB } --open bracket
    ')'  { TokenCB } --closing bracket
    '.' {TokenEnd}

%left "<=>"
%left "=>"
%left or
%left and
%left '¬'
%left '(' ')'
%%

--Grammar
Prop :: {Sentence}
Prop : Sentence '.' {$1}

Sentence :: {Sentence}
Sentence : AtomSent {Atom $1}
    | CompSent {Comp $1}

AtomSent :: {AtomSent}
AtomSent : var { Variable $1 }

CompSent :: {CompSent}
CompSent : '(' Sentence ')' { Bracket $2 }
    | Sentence Connective Sentence {Bin $2 $1 $3}
    | '¬' Sentence {Not $2}

Connective :: {Connective}
Connective : and {And}
    | or {Or}
    | "=>" {Imp}
    | "<=>" {DImp}


{
--Error function
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error ("parseError: Syntax analysis error.\n")

--Data types to represent the grammar
data Sentence
    = Atom AtomSent
    | Comp CompSent
    deriving Show

data AtomSent = Variable String deriving Show

data CompSent
      = Bin Connective Sentence Sentence
      | Not Sentence
      | Bracket Sentence
      deriving Show

data Connective
    = And
    | Or
    | Imp
    | DImp
    deriving Show

--Data types for the tokens
data Token
      = TokenVar String
      | TokenOr
      | TokenAnd
      | TokenNot
      | TokenImp
      | TokenDImp
      | TokenOB
      | TokenCB
      | TokenEnd
      deriving Show

--Lexer
lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer [] = []  -- cadena vacia
lexer (c:cs)   -- cadena es un caracter, c, seguido de caracteres, cs.
      | isSpace c = lexer cs
      | isAlpha c = lexVar (c:cs)
      | isSymbol c = lexSym (c:cs)
      | c== '(' = TokenOB : lexer cs
      | c== ')' = TokenCB : lexer cs
      | c== '¬' = TokenNot : lexer cs --solved
      | c== '.'  = [TokenEnd]
      | otherwise = error "lexer:  Token invalido"

lexVar cs =
   case span isAlpha cs of
      ("or",rest) -> TokenOr : lexer rest
      ("and",rest)  -> TokenAnd : lexer rest
      (var,rest)   -> TokenVar var : lexer rest

lexSym cs =
    case span isSymbol cs of
        ("=>",rest) -> TokenImp : lexer rest
        ("<=>",rest) -> TokenDImp : lexer rest
}
```

Now, I have two problems here

1. For some reason I get 4 shift/reduce conflicts, I don't really know where they might be since I thought the precedence would solve them (and I think I followed the BNF grammar correctly)...
2. (this is rather a Haskell problem) On my lexer function, for some reason I get parsing errors on the line where I say what to do with '¬', if I remove that line it's works, why could that be? (this issue is solved)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

If you use happy with `-i` it will generate an info file. The file lists all the states that your parser has. It will also list all the possible transitions for each state. You can use this information to determine if the shift/reduce conflict is one you care about.

Information about invoking happy and conflicts:

- http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-invoking.html
- http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-conflict-tips.html

Below is some of the output of `-i`. I've removed all but State 17. You'll want to get a copy of this file so that you can properly debug the problem. What you see here is just to help talk about it:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Info file generated by Happy Version 1.18.10 from FNC.y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

state 17 contains 4 shift/reduce conflicts.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grammar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %start_parse -> Prop                               (0)
    Prop -> Sentence '.'                               (1)
    Sentence -> AtomSent                               (2)
    Sentence -> CompSent                               (3)
    AtomSent -> var                                    (4)
    CompSent -> '(' Sentence ')'                       (5)
    CompSent -> Sentence Connective Sentence           (6)
    CompSent -> '¬' Sentence                          (7)
    Connective -> and                                  (8)
    Connective -> or                                   (9)
    Connective -> "=>"                                 (10)
    Connective -> "<=>"                                (11)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var            { TokenVar $$ }
    or             { TokenOr }
    and            { TokenAnd }
    '¬'           { TokenNot }
    "=>"           { TokenImp }
    "<=>"          { TokenDImp }
    '('            { TokenOB }
    ')'            { TokenCB }
    '.'            { TokenEnd }

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Non-terminals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %start_parse    rule  0
    Prop            rule  1
    Sentence        rules 2, 3
    AtomSent        rule  4
    CompSent        rules 5, 6, 7
    Connective      rules 8, 9, 10, 11

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
States
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
State 17

    CompSent -> Sentence . Connective Sentence          (rule 6)
    CompSent -> Sentence Connective Sentence .          (rule 6)

    or             shift, and enter state 12
            (reduce using rule 6)

    and            shift, and enter state 13
            (reduce using rule 6)

    "=>"           shift, and enter state 14
            (reduce using rule 6)

    "<=>"          shift, and enter state 15
            (reduce using rule 6)

    ')'            reduce using rule 6
    '.'            reduce using rule 6

    Connective     goto state 11

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grammar Totals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of rules: 12
Number of terminals: 9
Number of non-terminals: 6
Number of states: 19
```

That output basically says that it runs into a bit of ambiguity when it's looking at connectives. It turns out, the slides you linked mention this (Slide 11), "ambiguities are resolved through precedence ¬∧∨⇒⇔ or parentheses".

At this point, I would recommend looking at the shift/reduce conflicts and your desired precedences to see if the parser you have will do the right thing. If so, then you can safely ignore the warnings. If not, you have more work for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer No. 2:

```
| c== '¬' == TokenNot : lexer cs --problem here
--        ^^
```

You have a `==` there where you should have a `=`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel (just what was I thinking...?)

Comment: You just typo'ed. Happens all the time. And one's own typos are always very hard to spot, that's why it didn't jump out to you.